# Up Arrow Before Submenu Background

Tags: css

I'm working on this project: http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/

In the top area navigation (Home, About, Contact, Work With Me), I have a submenu drop down. The only active link is "About" - when you hover over it, the submenu appears, as does the up-arrow before it, however, I can't make the background of the up-arrow go away. It should be transparent, but it is showing up as the same pink color as the submenu.

Thanks in advance.

```css
#top-navigation {
 float: left;
 padding-top: 4px;
}

#top-navigation ul {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}

#top-navigation ul a {
 display: block;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#top-navigation ul a:hover {
 color: #f68364;
}

#top-navigation ul li {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 10px;
}

#top-navigation ul li:hover {
 color: #f68364;
}

#top-navigation ul ul:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 background: transparent !important;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #6d5d68;
}

#top-navigation ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 width: 150px;
 background: #f68364;
}

#top-navigation ul ul li {
 float: none;
 margin: 0px;
}

#top-navigation ul ul a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
}

#top-navigation ul ul a:hover {
 background: #6d5d68;
 color: #ffffff;
}

#top-navigation ul ul ul {
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
}

#top-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="top-navigation">
<ul>

<li>
<a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/">Home</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Work With Me</a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you aware that if you do accomplish what you are attempting, you'll be faced with two other presumably unintended side effects?  First, you won't be able to see the arrow because its color matches the navigation background; and second, it will be difficult to hover over the submenu because the orange background is maintaining the hover state as you move your mouse down into the submenu.

Comment: I will be changing the color to pink, I only have it purple now to show that it's there. As for the second problem, can I just change the background color to the purple then so that it is still there but not visible? If so, how?

Comment: Nevermind - worked it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to my comment, there may be unintended side effects if you try to maintain a background color on the `<ul>`.  I recommend removing the `background: #f68364` from `#top-navigation ul ul` and instead adding it to `#top-navigation ul ul li`.  I also recommend changing `border-bottom: 10px solid #6d5d68;` on `#top-navigation ul ul:before` to `border-bottom: 10px solid #f68364;`

Answer (score 0):

Move `background: #f68364;` from `#top-navigation ul ul` to `#top-navigation ul ul a`

```
#top-navigation ul ul a {
display: block;
padding: 10px;
background: #f68364;
}
```

```css
#top-navigation {
 float: left;
 padding-top: 4px;
}

#top-navigation ul {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}

#top-navigation ul a {
 display: block;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#top-navigation ul a:hover {
 color: #f68364;
}

#top-navigation ul li {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 10px;
}

#top-navigation ul li:hover {
 color: #f68364;
}

#top-navigation ul ul:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 background: transparent !important;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #6d5d68;
}

#top-navigation ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 width: 150px;
 
}

#top-navigation ul ul li {
 float: none;
 margin: 0px;
}

#top-navigation ul ul a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
  background: #f68364;
}

#top-navigation ul ul a:hover {
 background: #6d5d68;
 color: #ffffff;
}

#top-navigation ul ul ul {
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
}

#top-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="top-navigation">
<ul>

<li>
<a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/">Home</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Work With Me</a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>
```